# Creating api for android with http requests

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

if I want to creat methode getToken("username",pasword); for a class that handels httprequest (JsonObjectRequest) and returns String(or any other value) -what is the best practice to achive that ?

-ofc I manage to retrive token to mainActivity with help of callbacks but I would like creat class that handles all requests and then just call f.i "getToken(username,password)" without needing to implement  any interfaces/callbacks in MainActivity

Comment: Just make getToken return the token directly without threading. In the consumer code, you can call this method through an AsyncTask or Loader. If the logic and code structure is simple, use AsyncTask. If you find it cluttering your code, then use loaders.

Comment: @Ammar will give it a try - ty Sir